# React Native - How to get image size (width and height) from device storage?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project built on expo. 
I need to view an image on screen with a style that is based on the width and height of that image. 
How can I get the width and height of that image?

let's say the image uri is `file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20200117-WA0019.jpg`

A solution with a code sample is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

React Native Image provide [getSize()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#getsize) to get the size of remote images.

```
Image.getSize('uri', (width, height) => {
  this.setState({ width, height });
});
```

For local images you can use [resolveAssetSource()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resolveassetsource)

```
Image.resolveAssetSource(source).width
Image.resolveAssetSource(source).height
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I tried `Image.resolveAssetSource` before but didn't work. it is returning the `uri` only without  returning the `width` and `height`. the following code logs `undefined`: `<Button
            title="get width"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(
                Image.resolveAssetSource({
                  uri:
                    "file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20200117-WA0019.jpg"
                }).width
              );
            }}`

Comment: try to load local images as ```Image.resolveAssetSource(require('path')).width```

Comment: any update? I tested this with local images & it works fine.

Comment: what did you pass as an argument for the `require` function (i.e. `'path'`)? it is trying to get the file form my PC when passing `"file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20200117-WA0019.jpg"`